# Got an error trying to update a database with Liquibase doesn't know how to deal with it

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, liquibase

I'm trying to test a liquibase update command on a database but I'm getting this error:

> Error executing SQL UPDATE postgres.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = 'ITEM-**** (********)', LOCKGRANTED = '2020-06-30 10:16:00.444' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE: ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint = boolean

It seems like it's not from my changelog files but from the initialization of liquibase who create the databasechangeloglock table. I'm using a postgresql database.

If you already experienced that or know what is the problem.

Comment: How was `databasechangeloglock` created? Liquibase creates it automatically with a `boolean` column when run against Postgres. Did you maybe copy the table definition from a different database system?

Comment: databasechangeloglock is created automatically by Liquibase yes, i haven't specified anything about it

Comment: Hmm, for me, Liquibase creates it properly with a `boolean` column. What is your Liquibase  version?

Comment: I'm on Liquibase Version 3.9.0

Comment: I resolved the problem by deleting the table manually and then it worked i don't know why

Comment: Maybe it was created with an older Liquibase version?